# Why GSM modem's own applications have not delivery report?

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I want to get sms delivery report with my own windows application by using AT commands.

but when i send my sms i just get the ok message how can i do this?
what command i should send after sms sending to my network?

I have a Nokia 6630 phone and D-LinkDWM156 GSM modem and Huawei E171 GSM Modem.
i installed all of them on my pc with their original windows applications and it's very interesting to me why all of theme have not delivery report for sent SMS(text message).

when you sent a sms from their own applications there is no place to find that sms has been delivered or not, WHY?

to send sms

```
AT
AT+CMGF=0
AT+CMGS= + (sendData.Length / 2 - 1).ToString() //just to show
```

after sending i got this

```
+CMGS: 35   //i think it's sms index number on sim
```

to get report i send

```
"AT+CNMI=2,1,2,2,0"
```

and got "ok" and nothing else

Comment: Hi! Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251903/how-to-handle-delivery-report-in-gsm-modem

Comment: @agent5566 i tried all links and questions on stack-overflow but did not find any right solution

Comment: could you please attach full command\answer listing?

Comment: looks like report not requested during sms sending, check http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/ , param `bit 5 SRR Set this bit to request a delivery report`